# Turn on GPS with XAMARIN

Tags: xamarin, gps, android-gps

How can I turn on the GPS if fhe GPS is turn off with XAMARIN  in Android system?

My devices is not rooted.

Comment: you have to prompt the user to turn it on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could invoke the corresponding system dialog.

Check if GPS is available, if not, navigate to system Settings to turn it on.

```
 protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        checkGPSEnabled();
    }

 private void checkGPSEnabled()
    {
        LocationManager manager = GetSystemService(Context.LocationService) as LocationManager;
        if (!manager.IsProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GpsProvider))
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionLocat‌​ionSourceSettings);
            intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop | ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            StartActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

Comment: In that way , the App will turn on the GPS without any action from user?

Comment: @Buflow No,it navigates to the Settings screen, requiring the user to manually turn it on.